# Does Trello support the idea of projects?

Tags: trello

My company is using Trello for software project management across multiple projects, and it would be convenient to organize boards by projects.  Currently, we have a board for `Project A: Use Cases`, `Project A: Stuff to do`, `Project B: Use Cases`, and so on.  But it would be more convenient to have a `Project A` entity, with boards called just `Use Cases` and `Stuff to do`, and only people who are associated with Project A see those boards.  Right now, we just have a flat list of boards, which everyone in the organization can see, and we have to rely on naming convention to keep these straight.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What about making a separate organization for each project?  So organization "Project A" has boards 'Use Cases' and 'Stuff To Do'.

Downside would be having to add everyone to multiple organizations.

Comment: I could do that, but it seems really kludgy.  Although maybe if we decided that "Organization" really means "Team", it seems less so.  I have to think about this some more, I guess.